# Green / teal port on portable charger

Tags: port, charger

This should mean it support the Qualcomm fast charging. I'd like to know if it is possible to plug-in a normal usb-A cable to this port to fast charge the device, or it is needed a particular cable (probably also with a green / teal colour in its plug)

Thanks. It is a Huawei P9 with FCP protocol. I have not the fast charger: the package didn't give it, it was optional; I have only the standard charger 5V-2A, so I wonder if the corresponding cable can fit the green port of the portable charger, a Tronsmart pbt10 (for which it is stated to support also FCP)

Comment: Do you mean teal instead of tea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *probably* does not require a special cable, but the device that's being charged must support Qualcomm's proprietary quick charge technology.

It's *possible* that an excessively cheaply-made cable could have such skinny power conductors inside it that it would cause too much resistance and heat the cable up too much, but that seems unlikely.